# Animate function error

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, animation, mathematica-online

I'm new to Mathematica and I'm trying to plot a interactive graph of a curve with a slider that shows the tangent to the curve in whichever point of the interval, my implementation is

```
curveC = {(-1 + t^3)/(1 + t^2), t/2 - 2 t^2};
intervalC = {-1, 1}
tangentC = D[curveC, t]
Manipulate[
Show[ParametricPlot[{curveC[t], {t, interval[[1]], interval[[2]]}},
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}],
Graphics[{  {Thick, Darker @ Red, Arrow[{curveC[s], curveC[s] + tangentC[s]}]}
  }]], {s, -1, 1}]
```

and I recieve the following error

```
Coordinate {(1 + $CellContext`t^2)^(-1) (-1 + $CellContext`t^3), Rational[1, 2] $CellContext`t - 2 $CellContext`t^2}[-1] should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.
```

I don't know what that error means.

Comment: (1) remove the outer curly braces from `{curveC[t], {t, interval[[1]], interval[[2]]}}`; (2) replace `interval` with `intervalC` ; (3) Use `curveC[t_] = ...`  and `tangentC[t_] = ...` when defining these functions; and -- just in case -- (4) use `ClearAll[curveC, tangentC]` at the start of your code block.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I fixed it accordingly and I still got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curveC = {(-1 + t^3)/(1 + t^2), t/2 - 2 t^2};
intervalC = {-1, 1}
tangentC = D[curveC, t]

Manipulate[
 Show[ParametricPlot[curveC, {t, intervalC[[1]], intervalC[[2]]}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}], 
  Graphics[{{Thick, Darker @ Red, 
     Arrow[{curveC, curveC + tangentC} /. t -> s]}}]], {s, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: I figured it out on my own and arrived at the same solution, yours is more elegant however. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Benjamin, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.